# Excel file needing a recovery when I create a file that uses UNIQUE function with openpyxl

Tags: formula, openpyxl

I am trying to get the UNIQUE entries on a column and later count how many times they have occurred.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Goose | 23000 |
| Duck | 6000 |
| Penguin | 46 |
| Ostrich | 120 |

```
def add_statistics(ws, data_start_row, data_end_row):
    first = ws.max_row + 1
    ws.append([f"=SORT(UNIQUE(G{data_start_row}:G{data_end_row}))", f"=COUNTIF(G{data_start_row}:G{data_end_row}, A{first})"])
    ws.append(["", f"=COUNTIF(G{data_start_row}:G{data_end_row}, A{first+1})"])
    ws.append(["", f"=COUNTIF(G{data_start_row}:G{data_end_row}, A{first+2})"])
    ws.append(["", f"=COUNTIF(G{data_start_row}:G{data_end_row}, A{first+3})"])
    ws.append(["", f"=COUNTIF(G{data_start_row}:G{data_end_row}, A{first+4})"])
```

When I try to open the resulting excel file, it needs recovery and deletion of the `f"=SORT(UNIQUE(G{data_start_row}:G{data_end_row}))"` formula. I don't have the problem if I just manually append the UNIQUE entries or use the formula later on when I open the file and write it manually.

Is the spilling not supported by openpyxl or is there a step I need to take before I can safely use a spill formula?

Comment: Openpyxl just enters the formula text you set into the formula for the cell . Openpyxl does not interpret or do anything with the formula. It's Excel that runs the formula and thus iterprets and executes what is entered. So Openpyxl supporting spilling is moot. I dont see any problem with the formula being written that would cause the workbook to fail to open so long as your version of Excel supports the function 'SORT' which appears it does if you can enter it manually.

Comment: If only someone would document this… oh, we did https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simple_formulae.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openpyxl does not support neither "SORT" nor "UNIQUE". According to the documentation:

> If you’re trying to use a formula that isn’t known this could be because you’re using a formula that was not included in the initial specification. Such formulae must be prefixed with _xlfn. to work.

I checked this by importing `FORMULAE` and checking if they are in that set:

```
from openpyxl.utils import FORMULAE
"UNIQUE" in FORMULAE
False
"SORT" in FORMULAE
False
```

Adding `_xlfn` solves the error but adds `@` at the start of the formula preventing it to leak into the other cells.

```
f"=_xlfn.SORT(_xlfn.UNIQUE(G{data_start_row}:G{data_end_row}))"
```

Using `ArrayFormula`, we can define a range of cells that we want to apply the formula. So in the end my code looked like this:

```
def add_statistics(ws, data_start_row, data_end_row):
    first = ws.max_row + 1
    ws.append(["", f"=COUNTIF(G{data_start_row}:G{data_end_row}, A{first})"])
    ws.append(["", f"=COUNTIF(G{data_start_row}:G{data_end_row}, A{first+1})"])
    ws.append(["", f"=COUNTIF(G{data_start_row}:G{data_end_row}, A{first+2})"])
    ws.append(["", f"=COUNTIF(G{data_start_row}:G{data_end_row}, A{first+3})"])
    ws.append(["", f"=COUNTIF(G{data_start_row}:G{data_end_row}, A{first+4})"])
    ws[f"A{first}"] = ArrayFormula(f"A{first}:A{first+4}", f"=_xlfn.SORT(_xlfn.UNIQUE(g{data_start_row}:g{data_end_row}))")
```

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simple_formulae.html#id1